# Difference between merge and create unique in Neo4j

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between MERGE and CREATE UNIQUE. I know these features:

#MERGE#
I'm able to create node, if doesn't exist pattern.

```
MERGE (n { name:"X" }) RETURN n;
```

This create node "n" with property name, empty node "m" and relationship RELATED.

```
MERGE (n { name:"X" })-[:RELATED]->(m) RETURN n, m;
```

#CREATE UNIQUE#
I'm not able to create node like this.

```
CREATE UNIQUE (n { name:"X" }) RETURN n;
```

If exists node "n", create unique makes empty node "m" and relationship RELATED.

```
MATCH (n { name: 'X' }) CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:RELATED]->(m) RETURN n, m;
```

If this pattern exists, nothing created, only returns pattern.

From my point of view, I see MERGE and CREATE UNIQUE are quite same queries, but with CREATE UNIQUE you can't create start node in relationship. I would be grateful if someone could explain this issue and compare these queries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`CREATE UNIQUE` has slightly more obscure semantics than `MERGE`. `MERGE` was developed as an alternative with more intuitive behavior than `CREATE UNIQUE`; if in doubt, `MERGE` is usually the right choice.

The easiest way to think of `MERGE` is as a MATCH-or-create. That is, if something in the database would `MATCH` the pattern you are using in `MERGE`, then `MERGE` will just return that pattern. If nothing matches, the `MERGE` will create all missing elements in the pattern, where a missing element means any unbound identifier.

**Given**

```
MATCH (a {uid:123})
MERGE (a)-[r:LIKES]->(b)-[:LIKES]->(c)
```

"a" is a bound identifier from the perspective of the MERGE. This means cypher somehow already knows which node it represents.

This statement can have two outcomes. Either the whole pattern already exists, and nothing will be created, or parts of the pattern are missing, and a whole new set of relationships and nodes matching the pattern will be created.

**Examples**

```
// Before merge:
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:LIKES]->()

// After merge:
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:LIKES]->()


// Before merge:
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:OWNS]->()

// After merge:
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:OWNS]->()
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:LIKES]->()


// Before merge:
(a)

// After merge:
(a)-[:LIKES]->()-[:LIKES]->()
```

Comment: why would you ever use just Create when you have Merge?

Comment: `CREATE` is usually a lot faster. `CREATE` simply creates what you've told it to, while `MERGE` must perform the equivalent `MATCH` clause and advanced locking to ensure no-one else creates the same pattern at the same time. You can speed up many `MERGE` statements by creating a uniqueness constraint that `MERGE` can rely on though.

Comment: @jakewins *The easiest way to think of MERGE is as a MATCH-or-create.* which is not Atomic if you don't have a unique constraint, which threw me off completely. Naming it `MERGE` and making in not atomic is really bad :( I started getting deadlock errors after adding a unique index which again gave me a hard time. So, my question is this: why would I want to use a `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` where I have a unique constraint?

Comment: You're right - this is confusing, confusing enough that I was apparently wrong in my comment above :( MERGE is useful when you are adding parts to existing nodes in the graph, like in my examples above. If you are adding individual, detached, nodes and have a uniqueness constraint, CREATE and MERGE are equivalent. Eg. if you are only creating individual nodes without relationships, there is no reason to use MERGE that I can think of.

Comment: @tugberk For a single node pattern and when your query challenges the uniqueness constraint: if you use `CREATE` you get an exception, if you use `MERGE` you get the node.

Comment: @jakewins can you provide for CREATE UNIQUE being deprecated? I can't find any mention of that, and I've gone through the list of deprecations for several version between 1.9.9 and 3.0.0-M05. As of 3.0.0-M05, CREATE UNIQUE is still listed in the docs, with no mention of deprecation.

Comment: I cannot find where CREATE UNIQUE is being deprecated either. CREATE UNIQUE is helpful when you want to ensure you aren't creating multiple relationships between the same two nodes. Merge does not account for this.

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez you're absolutely right; when I wrote this, my understanding was that we were going to deprecate `CREATE UNIQUE`, and I kept holding off editing the answer anticipating that we'd officially announce deprecation.

However, it never did get deprecated, remaining a fully supported feature. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Just clear things out: Create Unique seems deprecated in 2018. http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/