# "Create Unique" not creating relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a relationship between two entities using **match** and **create unique** functionality in **neo4j** but unfortunately it's not making any changes in the database or records. Following is my statement. How should i modify it?

```
MATCH (city:City{name:'Prague'}), (street:Street{code:'SVK'})
CREATE UNIQUE (street)-[:BASED_IN]-(city) ;
```

Comment: Do those entities exist? I created those using `MATCH (city:City{name:'Prague'}), (street:Street{code:'SVK'})` and ran your query, which worked well and created the required edge. Also, did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773562/difference-between-merge-and-create-unique-in-neo4j

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas thanks. there was an issue with my entities but there is another statement having the "WHERE" clause in it which i am unable to execute and in this case the entities are have been defined correctly.
    `MATCH (room:Room), (house:House{code:1})
    WHERE id(room) = 40
     CREATE UNIQUE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(house) ;`

what could be the issue here?

Comment: I'm not sure about this issue, but a couple of observations: 1. Please edit your question and add this query 2. Neo4j engineers noted that [using internal ids is practice](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/) and you should provide your own id attributes. So the `room` node should have an attribute (which might be called `id`) and you should use that in your `MATCH` clause as `(room:Room {id:...})`. I'm not sure this will fix your issues but it's worth a try.

Comment: Your syntax is correct (even if - as was correctly pointed out - you should not use internal ids). If you run the two matches by themselves, so MATCH (room:Room) WHERE id(room) = 40 RETURN room; and MATCH (house:House{code :1}) RETURN house ... do you get results ?

Comment: @TomGeudens the match query for house returns the results but the match query for room does not returns any results

Comment: @RehanAziz And there you just stated the reason the subsequent CREATE is not working. So there is no Room with internal id 40.

Comment: @TomGeudens ok. so i tried running the statements without room id and it created relationships as per your guidance but how should i include the **id** into the original query so that it creates the room with that particular id if it's not previously created. that's what i wanted to do with my original query with **create unique**

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not make sense. You can not determine the internal id for any node. Are you also trying to create a non-existing room first ? What would your identifier for it (roomID or something) be ? I suggest you close this question and post a new question with what you are actually trying to do. Your original question has been answered ... things do not work because your MATCHes do not return data.

Comment: @TomGeudens Please find here the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526337/creating-relationships-between-nodes-with-where-clause-and-using-id-in-neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The match statement runs fine. It was my creation of entities that had issue. I had missed a colon in it :). Here is how i created it.

```
CREATE (n:City { name: 'Prague', code: 'PRG'})
CREATE (n:City { name: 'Kiev', code: 'KIV'})
CREATE (n:City { name: 'Berlin', code :'BRN'})
CREATE (n:street { name: 'Shveyk', code: 'SVK'})
CREATE (n:street { name: 'Kreshatik', code: 'KRS'})
CREATE (n:street { name: 'Unter den Linden', code: 'UDL'})
```