# Creating relationships between nodes with WHERE clause and using ID in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes named Room(4) and Houses(4). They have been created in the following way:

```
CREATE (n:Room { code: 1})
CREATE (n:Room { code: 1})
CREATE (n:Room { code: 1})
CREATE (n:Room { code: 1})

CREATE (n:House { code: 1})
CREATE (n:House { code: 2})
CREATE (n:House { code: 3})
CREATE (n:House { code: 4})
```

These are some of the relations that i am trying to create between the nodes

```
MATCH (room:Room), (house:House{code:1})
WHERE id(room) = 40
CREATE UNIQUE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(house) ;
MATCH (room:Room), (house:House{code:2})
WHERE id(room) = 41
CREATE UNIQUE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(house) ;
MATCH (room:Room), (house:House{code:3})
WHERE id(room) = 42
CREATE UNIQUE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(house) ;
```

The ID's have not been defined before so it should be creating new rooms based on ID's or should i add the ID's manually while creating as currently the relationships are not being created due to WHERE clause?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your problem? I think I don't understand it completely.

Comment: @BrunoPeres The relationships between nodes are not being created when using ID but when i try to create them without ID then they are created. i want to create relationship between a particular room with an ID and a House with a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
// match room by internal id
MATCH (room:Room)
WHERE id(room) = 40
// merge will create a relationship between `room.id = 40`
// and `house.code = 1`. If `house.code = 1` does not exists, it will be created
MERGE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(:House {code:1}) ;
MATCH (room:Room)
WHERE id(room) = 41
MERGE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(:House {code:2}) ;
MATCH (room:Room)
WHERE id(room) = 42
MERGE (room)-[:PLACED_IN]->(:House {code:3}) ;
```

Some tips:

- Avoid depending on Neo4j internal `IDs` because the are not safe. [Neo4j 
  reuses these IDs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-node-by-id) when nodes and relationships are deleted.
- `CREATE UNIQUE` is deprecated. Use `MERGE` instead.